# Syncing previously Instantiated Objects when new player joins

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I'm currently working on a survival game where "zombies" spawn and chase the player over a map. The zombies are instantiated by `InstantiateSceneObject` on the `zombie_spawner` object.

The problem is that an already connected player can see the zombies, whereas new players joining don't see them. New players will only see the zombies instantiated after they join the game.

What method(s) should I call to create the “old” zombies for the new player when they join the game already in progress?

Here is what I have so far for spawning new zombies on the master client:

```
if (!PhotonNetwork.isMasterClient)
    return;
GameObject zb = PhotonNetwork.InstantiateSceneObject(zombie_name, transform.position + transform.up, Quaternion.identity, 0, null);
```

This should have the master client manage the spawn, and spawn new enemies when the time has come. Is this the right way? How can I then sync already instantiated zombies for players other than the master client?

Comment: Please do not repeat [tag] [info] in your title.. The tag system works extremely well, and does not need help. People watching the tags who can answer your question will see the tags. Redundantly adding them to your title is useless clutter. Thanks.

Comment: You should have all ative "zomby" instances registered in a list on the server and sync this list to clients and let them create zombies which are "missing" on them

Answer (score 1):

You could try implementing an RPC call from the master client.

On Player Script:

```
if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
    {
        photonView.RPC("SpawnZombieFromMaster", RpcTarget.AllBuffered);
    }

[PunRPC]
void SpawnZombieFromMaster()
    {
        ZombieSpawner.instance.SpawnZombie();
    }
```

And on your singleton "ZombieSpawner" script:

```
public void SpawnZombie()
    {
        GameObject zb = PhotonNetwork.InstantiateSceneObject(zombie_name, transform.position + transform.up, Quaternion.identity, 0, null)
    }
```